# database mirror problem with Network Service account

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

I have two SQL Server 2008 R2 instances installed on same Server and the engine log on as Network Service account which is set by installation.

there is a database TestDB on both instances. I try to setup database mirror for this case and I failed with following error:

> The server network address "TCP://myserver.mycompany.com:5023" can not be reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1418)

Then I changed the account to Local System for engine and restarted sql server service and I am able to setup mirror.

How to resolve this problem if I want to keep Network Service to run the engine service?

Comment: What does, sys.database_mirroring_endpoints joined with sys.tcp_endpoints on the principle and mirror say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "unclear" since you have not provided any reason for using the Network Service account, and as explained in the answer below, that has its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Use a local system account, or create a local or domain account.

The [`NetworkService` account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx) has its limitations as that documentation explains.